# label on the x-axis does not show completely in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, chart.js, bar-chart, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a data from the backend(flask-sqlalchemy with mysql) in which data contains date in integer for week, month and year that looks like this:

in this case the x represents the week of the year:

```
let month_true = [
  {
    bob: {
      "base-certificate": 60,
      "case-certificate": 1,
      "standard-certificate": 7,
    },
    x: 9,
  },
  {
    bob: {
      "base-certificate": 30,
      "case-certificate": 4,
      "standard-certificate": 5,
    },
    x: 11,
  },
];
```

The first thing I did was to map the data and change the x into a readable format for Javascript and chart.js, using a function that converts week of the year number to actual date:

the function:

```
 function getDateOfWeek(w, y) {
      var d = 1 + (w - 1) * 7; // 1st of January + 7 days for each week
    
      return new Date(y, 0, d);
    }
```

Mapping through the data:

```
let newData = month_true.map(function (m) {
  let dateObject = new Date();
  let year = dateObject.getFullYear();
  const weekDate = getDateOfWeek(m.x, year);

  let r = new Date(Date.parse(weekDate));
  const newd = {
    x: r.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0),
    base: m.bob["base-certificate"],
    case: m.bob["case-certificate"],
    standard: m.bob["standard-certificate"],
  };
  return newd;
});

let newdate = newData.map(function (d) {
  return d.x;
});
```

now construct the chart:

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
let config = {
  //labels: newdate,
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "base",
        data: newData,
        parsing: {
          xAxisKey: "x",
          yAxisKey: "base",
        },
      },
      {
        label: "Case",
        data: newData,
        parsing: {
          xAxisKey: "x",
          yAxisKey: "case",
        },
      },
      {
        label: "Standard",
        data: newData,
        parsing: {
          xAxisKey: "x",
          yAxisKey: "standard",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        offset: true,
        type: "time",
        time: {
          //isoWeekday: true,
          unit: "week",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

let myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

It got plotted but the x-axis is not showing the second label:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX058.png)

what can I can do tomake the labels appear completely?

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default the time scale auto generates ticks, if you dont want to include the labels from your data you need to set ticks.source to data:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'time',
      ticks: {
        source: 'data'
      }
    }
  }
}
```